# what are the permissions required to assign a resource monitor to a warehouse?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have SYSADMIN role on a Snowflake account which does not allow me to create warehouses or Resource Monitors.
Someone with ACCOUNTADMIN created a couple of warehouses and resource monitors for me.
He granted SYSADMIN ownership on both warehouses and resource monitors.

Yet, if I try to assign a resource monitor to a warehouse

```
ALTER WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH_XS SET RESOURCE_MONITOR = 'LIMITER_XS';
```

I get the following error msg

[image]

Again, SYSADMIN owns both objects...

Any idea?

The documentation says that only ACCOUNTADMIN can create RESOURCE MONITORs... but does that also apply to assigning a Warehouse to a RESOURCE MONITOR?

[image]

I can modify the RESOURCE MONITORs but I can't assigna  warehouse to it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Assigning Warehouses to a Resource Monitor](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/resource-monitors#assigning-warehouses-to-a-resource-monitor)

> Warehouses can be assigned to an existing resource monitor through either the web interface or SQL.
>
> **Only account administrators (users with the ACCOUNTADMIN role) can assign warehouses to resource monitors. This role must also have the MODIFY privilege on each warehouse.**